# Finding number of solutions nqueens 14 by 14 chessboard

Tags: python, programming-challenge, n-queens

I have written a code to solve the N-Queen problem for a 14 by 14 chessboard. There are preplaced queens (see below for the sample input and output). The lines of sample input (after the 3) represent the positions of the preplaced queens. For example, "1 1 2 9 3 6 4 10" refers to the 4 preplaced queens are at (1st row 1st column), (2nd row, 9th column), (3rd row 6th column), (4th row, 10th column).

I am hoping that it will return me the number of solutions. But when I tried running the code, I got time limit exceeded, even for the sample input.

I will try the list of tuples method, but let me know if there is a more efficient implementation. Thanks in advance

[![Question screenshot][1]][1]

```
Sample Input
3
1 1 2 9 3 6 4 10
1 9 12 8 8 5 2 7
2 10 10 3

Sample Output
39
32
2414
```

```
import sys


def nQueens(n, pre_placed_rows, pre_placed_cols, N, state=[], col=1):  
    if col > n: return [state]
    res = []

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if invalid(state, i): continue
        for sol in nQueens(n, pre_placed_rows, pre_placed_cols, N, state + [i], col+1): 
            if N == 2: # 2 preplaced queens
                if sol[pre_placed_cols[0]-1] == pre_placed_rows[0] and sol[pre_placed_cols[1]-1] == pre_placed_rows[1]: 
                    res.append(sol) #[sol]
            elif N == 3:  # 3 preplaced queens
                if sol[pre_placed_cols[0]-1] == pre_placed_rows[0] and sol[pre_placed_cols[1]-1] == pre_placed_rows[1] and sol[pre_placed_cols[2]-1] == pre_placed_rows[2]:
                    res.append(sol)
            else: # 4 preplaced queens
                if sol[pre_placed_cols[0]-1] == pre_placed_rows[0] and sol[pre_placed_cols[1]-1] == pre_placed_rows[1] and sol[pre_placed_cols[2]-1] == pre_placed_rows[2] and sol[pre_placed_cols[3]-1] == pre_placed_rows[3]:
                    res.append(sol)
    return res

def invalid(s, r2): # is it safe to put the queen 
    if not s: 
        return False
    if r2 in s: 
        return True
    c2 = len(s) + 1
    return any(abs(c1-c2) == abs(r1-r2) for c1, r1 in enumerate(s, 1))

num_case = int(sys.stdin.readline())
for _ in range(num_case):
    s = sys.stdin.readline().split()
    N = len(s) // 2
    pre_placed_rows = []
    pre_placed_cols = []
    n = 14
    for i in range(N):
        pre_placed_rows.append(int(s[2*i]))
        pre_placed_cols.append(int(s[2*i+1]))  
    
    print(len(nQueens(n, pre_placed_rows, pre_placed_cols, N)))
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review site. Please add a link to the programming challenge.

Comment: Hi pacman, I do not have the link, but I have attached the screenshot. The time allowed is 6000ms, 256MB memory. My current algo has taken more than a minute, but less than 10MB memory

Comment: How much more than a minute did it take? And did it produce the correct results?

Comment: Hi superb, it is taking 20minutes for the sample input. It produced the correct results

Comment: It looks like `nQueens()` constructs all possible solutions but drops those that don't have a queen in the pre-placed squares.  That's a lot of extra work.  `state` should start with the pre-placed queens already filed in and `nQueens()` should try to fill in the rest.

Comment: I tried. Not sure what I did wrong.

def nQueens(n, state=[], col=1):
  if col > n: return [state]
  res = []
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    if invalid(state, i): continue
    for sol in nQueens(n, state + [i], col+1): res += [sol]
  return res

def invalid(s, r2):
  if not s: return False
  if r2 in s: return True
  c2 = len(s) + 1
  return any(abs(c1-c2) == abs(r1-r2) for c1, r1 in enumerate(s, 1))
state = [1]
print(nQueens(14,state,col=1))

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on it.

Translate columns 1-14 to 0-13 for internal use and translate back on output.

`state` keeps track of where the queens are.  `state[0]` is the row of the queen in column 0, etc.  A None indicates the column is empty.

`nQueens()` searches `state` for an empty column and then checks each row in that column for a valid move.  If a move is valid, `state` is updated and `nQueens()` is called with the new state. After the recursive call is made, revert the change in state. That avoids the need to make a copy of the state.

The code `yield`s the solutions rather than keeping a list.

`printboard()` is just to help with visualizing what is going on.  Uncomment some of the calls if you're curious...but only do one of the smaller test cases because there is a lot of output.

I think your `imvalid()` might be off?

Put the driver code in `main()`.

```
SIZE = 14


def nQueens(state):
    #printboard(state)
    
    # find an empty column (row==None)
    for col, row in enumerate(state):
        if row is None:
            break
         
    # all columns filled. so it is a solution
    else:
        yield state
            
    for row in range(SIZE):
        # check if row taken
        if not valid(state, row, col):
            continue

        # make the move
        #print(f"col[{col+1}] = {row+1}")
        state[col] = row
        yield from nQueens(state)
        
        # revert the move to continue the search
        state[col] = None
            

def valid(state, row, col):
    # is there a queen in this row
    if row in state: 
        return False

    # is there a queen on a diagonal
    for c,r in enumerate(state):
        if r is None:
            continue
            
        if col-row == c-r or col+row == c+r:
            return False
                
    return True


def printboard(state):
    print('  '+' '.join(str(i%10) for i in range(1, SIZE+1)))
    for r in range(SIZE):
        print((r+1)%10, end=' ')
        for c in range(SIZE):
            if state[c] == r:
                print('Q', end=' ')
            else:
                print('.', end=' ')
        print()

        
def main(data):
    num_cases = int(data.readline())

    for case_num in range(num_cases):
        # initialize state to all Nones.
        # None means the corresponding column is empty
        state = [None]*SIZE

        # fill in the preset queens
        preset = data.readline().split()
        while preset:
            row = int(preset.pop(0)) - 1
            col = int(preset.pop(0)) - 1
            state[col] = row

        #printboard(state)

        # count the number of solutions
        for n,sol in enumerate(nQueens(state)):
            #printboard(sol)
            pass

        print(n+1)
```

Test it like so:

```
test = """
3
1 1 2 9 3 6 4 10
1 9 12 8 8 5 2 7
2 10 10 3
""".strip()

main(io.StringIO(test))
```

Or call it like:

```
main(sys.stdin)
```

Comment: Thanks RootTwo. Can I know which line will iterate all of the columns?

Comment: The columns are iterated using recursion.  `state`  is a list of the position (row) of the queen in each column.  That is, `state[0]` is the row of the queen in column 0, `state[1]` is the row of the queen in column 1, etc.  The `for col, row in enumerate(state):` loop searches `state` to find an empty column. Just before each recursive call to `nQueens()`, that empty column of `state` is filled in.  When `state` is full, that means every column has a queen. That should happen at the 10th, 11th, or 12th level of recursion depending on the number of preset queens.